# Отловить закрытие Windows

Tags: c#, winforms

Если программа работает в фоновом режиме, нажатие на "х" не закрывает ее, переводит в

```
ShowWindow(Handle, 0);
```

а, перед закрытии Windows, в программе надо провести сохранение каких-то параметров, потом закрыть ее и закрыть Windows?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/wm-queryendsession

Comment: Говоря "Windows" вы имеете в виду операционную систему? Или речь всё же об окнах приложения?

Comment: Какого типа приложение: WinForms, WPF, что-то другое?

Comment: [SystemEvents Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)

Comment: Что такое `ShowWindow`? Это функция WinAPI? Вы на каком языке пишете: C# или C++?

Comment: Отловить то надо закрытие чего, окна или приложения? Или отловить нажатие на "х"?

Comment: Извиняюсь за не правильно изложенную задачу.

Comment: C#, WinForms, закрытие ОС Windows

Comment: [DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int showCmds);

Comment: Что такое "закрытие Windows" - завершение работы? выход пользователя из системы? что именно? Событие `Form.FormClosing` пробовали использовать? `FormClosingEventArgs` содержат причину завершения приложения.

Comment: Завершение работы или Перезагрузка ОС

Comment: Событие **Form.FormClosing** переводит приложение в фоновый режим, там проходят процессы, которые надо сохранить при завершении работы ОС

Comment: Если вам нужны какие-то процессы, происходящие после закрытия приложения, создайте Службу Windows. Это общепринятая практика. В закрытом приложении не должно происходить никаких процессов, оно должно быть выгружено из памяти полностью. Тогда и вопросов как выше изложенный, возникать не будет. Втыкание костылей в логику работы приложения ни к чему хорошему обычно не приводит.

Comment: @aepot Да, мне нужна обычная логика работы: 1. Программа работает в фоновом режиме к ней обращаются делают какие-то действия и т.д. 2. Пользователь решил закрыть или перезагрузить ОС 3. Программа должна сохранить данные в обработке, закрыться и закрытие ОС.

Comment: @aepot , вы правильно, спасибо, написали **FormClosingEventArgs** отлавливает причину закрытия программы в том числе **e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown** закрытие ОС

Comment: **НО** возникла другая проблема, если данных мало для сохранения они 
успевают сохранится все ОК, если данных много не успевают, а ОС уже закрылась. Как сделать чтобы сначала данные полностью сохранились, потом ОС закрылась, приостановить на время закрытие ОС, до полного сохранения данных?

Comment: Для этого нужно видеть код, который их сохраняет. Вероятно он неблокирующий. И потом, время на сохранение все равно ограничено (несколько секунд), так что записаться должно быстро. Что такое в вашем понимании "много"? А вообще это тема для другого вопроса, который вы можете задать отдельно. Ответ ниже, если считаете его полезным, можете принять поставив зеленую галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: Да, так и сделаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используй событие SystemEvents.SessionEnding

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;

class Program
{
        static void Main()
        {
            //Добавляем в событие метод autosave()
            SystemEvents.SessionEnding += new SessionEndingEventHandler(autosave);

            //Просто чтобы консоль не закрывалась
            Console.WriteLine("tap any button for close window");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        //Собственно сам autosave:
        static void autosave(object sender, SessionEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            //Записаваем файл Readme.txt
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Readme.txt");
            sw.WriteLine("The automaticly saved file.");
            sw.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` событие еще есть.